# Re: ScaleImageLabel isnt working fine

Tags: codenameone

Used scaledImageButton class to scale fit the buttons in the grid cells but somehow it is not working well. When i keep the background behaviour type of scaleImageButton class to scale_Image_To_Fit, there are gaps in betn the grids and if i set it to scale_Image_To_FILL, the gaps created betn the grids above are replaced by its own scaled image. So there are two duplicate image seen in single grid cell. The codes and the screenshots are below:

My code:

```
    GridLayout gr = new GridLayout(1, 2);
    gr.setAutoFit(true);
    Container gridContainer = new Container(gr);
    gridContainer.setUIID("containerGridImgGallery");
    gridContainer.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gridContainer.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gridContainer.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createEmpty());
    gridContainer.setScrollableY(true);
    EncodedImage a = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, galleryPhotoTitle + offset + imageId + "bibek", galleryPhotoUrl, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL);
    ScaleImageButton scaleImageButton = new ScaleImageButton();
    scaleImageButton.setIcon(a);
    gridContainer.addComponent(scaleImageButton)
    f.addComponent(gridContainer);
    f.revalidate();
```

ScaleImageButton class:

```
public class ScaleImageButton extends Button {

    /**
     * Default constructor
     */
    public ScaleImageButton() {
        setUIID("Container");
        setShowEvenIfBlank(true);
        setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);
    }

    /**
     * Create a version with the given image
     *
     * @param i image
     */
    public ScaleImageButton(Image i) {
        setUIID("Container");
        setShowEvenIfBlank(true);
        setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT);
        setIcon(i);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the behavior of the background to one of
     * Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT,
     * Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL, Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALE
     *
     * @param behavior the background behavior
     */
    public void setBackgroundType(byte behavior) {
        getUnselectedStyle().setBackgroundType(behavior);
        getSelectedStyle().setBackgroundType(behavior);
        getPressedStyle().setBackgroundType(behavior);
    }

    public byte getBackgroundType() {
        return getUnselectedStyle().getBackgroundType();
    }

    @Override
    protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
        Image i = getIcon();
        if (i == null) {
            return new Dimension();
        }
        Style s = getStyle();
        return new Dimension(i.getWidth() + s.getPaddingLeft(false) + s.getPaddingRight(false), i.getHeight()
                + s.getPaddingTop() + s.getPaddingBottom());
    }

    public void setIcon(Image i) {
        getUnselectedStyle().setBgImage(i);
        getSelectedStyle().setBgImage(i);
        getPressedStyle().setBgImage(i);
    }

    public Image getIcon() {
        return getUnselectedStyle().getBgImage();
    }


    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
    }

    @Override
    public Image getIconFromState() {
        return getIcon();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUIID(String id) {
        Image icon = getIcon();
        super.setUIID(id);
        setIcon(icon);
    }
}
```

Background behaviour type to Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT

[image]

Background behaviour type to Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in [getAllStyles()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html#getAllStyles--) that we fixed recently. Try using `getUnselectedStyle()` to see if it resolves the issue until the next update.

Comment: i have used getAllStyles in gridContainer only ie for setting padding, margin and border. I replace them with getUnselectedStyle(), getSelectedStyle() and getPressedStyle but the result is same. There is reflected image in the background.

Comment: How did you change the value to scale image to fill? It looks like you changed it after using the fit code and somehow the fit code is still there? Also using "Container" for the UIID might be a bad idea, its transparent by default. Use a UIID that has bg transparency set to 255 to avoid drawing the other backgrounds in recursion.

Comment: I change the scale image to fill in ScaleImageButton constructor.  I used Label for the constructor, it didnt work so tried container as UIId. I tried Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED, Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FIT and Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL and cleaned storage too but the outcome is same

Comment: Did you set the bg transparency to 255?